# I can't access Auth0 api with Angular SPA

Tags: angular, authentication, azure-active-directory, auth0

I need help, my problem is this: I am onboarding my angular spa auth0 application (Microsoft Azure AD) and I am using @auth0/auth0-angular, I am trying to access Api Managment Auth0 and get the users https:// xxxx .auth0.com/api/v2/users, when I call this route it returns the following error

**{
"statusCode": 403,
"error": "Forbidden",
"message": "Insufficient scope, expected any of: read:users,read:user_idp_tokens",
"errorCode": "insufficient_scope"
}**

```
This is my app.module.ts

  AuthModule.forRoot({
      domain: 'xxx.auth0.com',
      clientId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
      /*useRefreshTokens: true,
      cacheLocation: 'localstorage',*/
      authorizationParams: {
        redirect_uri: window.location.origin,
        audience: "https://xxx.auth0.com/api/v2/",  
        scope: 'profile email read:users read:user_idp_tokens',      
      },
      httpInterceptor: {
        allowedList: [
          `${env.apiUrl}/api/messages/protected-message`,
          // Using an absolute URI
          {
            uri: 'https://xxx.auth0.com/api/v2/users',
            tokenOptions: {
              authorizationParams: {
                audience: 'https://xxx.auth0.com/api/v2/',
                scope: 'read:users read:user_idp_tokens',
              }
            },
          }
        
        ],
      }
    })
```

```
This is where I call the Auth0 Managment Api route

  this.http
      .get('https://xxx.auth0.com/api/v2/users')
      .subscribe((result) => {
        console.log(result);
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

To fix the `Insufficient scope, expected any of: read:users,read:user_idp_tokens` error when calling the Auth0 Management API from an Angular SPA, you need to ensure that your access token has the required scopes when calling the Auth0 Management API `/api/v2/users` endpoint,

Check that your Auth0 access token is valid and that you have the `read:users` scope.
[image]

i have achevied getting user data when I have added Scopes in app.module.ts also

```
imports: [
BrowserModule,
AppRoutingModule,
HttpClientModule,
AuthModule.forRoot({
  domain: 'xxx.auth0.com',
  clientId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
authorizationParams:{
redirect_uri:  window.location.origin,
audience:  "https://xxx.auth0.com/api/v2/",
scope:  'profile email read:users read:user_idp_tokens',
}
}),
],
```

**Result**
[image]